# How can I log values of effects given that we don't subsribe to them anywhere?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

What I understand yes we dont need to subscribe to effects like observables as we are not consuming the results,
for example like:

```ts
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

But is it possible to log without subscribing ?
Here is my code, say I want to log, addUserStats$ effect.

user-profile-effects.ts:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileEffects {

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private userProfileActions: UserProfileActions,
    private userProfile: UserProfile,
    private auth: Authorization
  ) { }

  @Effect()
  updateToken$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserProfileActions.UPDATE_TOKEN)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .map((token: string) => this.auth.accessToken = token)
    .switchMap(token => this.userProfile.getStats(true))
    .map(response => this.userProfileActions.updateData(response));

  @Effect()
  addUserStats$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserProfileActions.UPDATE)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .map((data: any) => this.userProfileActions.addStats(data.items));
}
```

effects.ts:

```ts
export default [
  NowStatEffects,
  UserProfileEffects
];
```

core.module.ts:

```ts
import effects from './effects';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreStoreModule,
    ...effects.map(effect => EffectsModule.run(effect)),
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CoreStoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...APP_SERVICES
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `.do(console.log)`. [This](http://blog.angular-university.io/debug-rxjs/) might be useful, also.

Comment: great it works, you can post it as answer if you have explanation of the difference with `.map(console.log)`

Comment: @Sasxa you might want to provide it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tap into observable stream by chaining [`do()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator. It will:

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source.

```ts
  @Effect()
  addUserStats$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(UserProfileActions.UPDATE)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .do((data: any) => console.log(data.items))
    .map(payload => { /* do something else */ )
```

or shorter version:

```
    .do(console.log)
```